# Magento 2 - Admin js config

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml

In Magento 2.3 inside of a template for the admin area:

> Moduel\Vendor\view\adminhtml\templates\template.phtml

I'm trying to add a button to open up the `MediabrowserUtility` with the url.

Code suggests doing this:

```
require(['jquery','mage/adminhtml/browser'
], function($) {return function(config) {
    $('.some-button').on('click',function(){
        /** @type Object */
        var cc = config['coreConfig'];
        /** @type String */
        var url = cc['files_browser_window_url'] + 'target_element_id/' + config.id + '/';
        /** @type ?Number */
        var storeId = cc['store_id'];
        if (storeId) {
            url += 'store/' + storeId;
        }
        MediabrowserUtility.openDialog(url);        
    });
};});
```

However `config` returns nothing. And clicking the button also does nothing. I don't fully understand where the config is coming from? How do I get that and action it?

I've not worked with admin area js before... so just wondering what the best thing to do is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the same as frontend Js logic. You need to pass the config by PHP script and `text/x-magento-init` json template.

Take a look at

`vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/review.phtml`

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Review/js/process-reviews": {
                "productReviewUrl": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getProductReviewUrl())) ?>",
                "reviewsTabSelector": "#tab-label-reviews"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

We can get the `productReviewUrl` and `reviewsTabSelector` from config object argument.

And `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js/process-reviews.js`

```
var reviewTab = $(config.reviewsTabSelector),
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It makes sense, but how do I get: \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config::getConfig() as config ?

Comment: Do you try with to encode and decode this config by `vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Serialize.php`?

Comment: No, I've not used the Serializer.

Comment: $this->getMediaConfig("cb-media-browser");